# How to use grep via awk?

Tags: awk, grep, gawk

I am trying to apply grep on just a few strings from a huge file. But, I'd like to pass that line to the grep command via the awk script. I also want the output redirected to the script. 
I've an awk script that reads in records from a file. I want grep to be applied on only a few of the records. The current record, $0, will be the text on which grep is to be used.
How do I do the same? Currently, I'm trying this -

```
system("grep --count -w 'GOOD' \n" $0)
```

But, it doesn't seem to work. What should I be using?

Comment: It better to show us some data, what you like out of it, and how to get there. This way we can help you to make a solution. I do not see the need of a `grep` inside an `awk`, it should be able to do it all.

Comment: Very seldom you need to grep the output from awk since awk is incredible flexible and powerful and can do everything that grep can do and more

Comment: @FredrikPihl is right. as you said, if you had a "huge" file, for each line, you started a grep process. grep is fast, but think about 10m lines. merge your grep logic into your awk, could probably gain better performance. From your current description of the question, the requirement is rather blur.

Comment: awk doesn't let me count the number of occurrences of a regular-expression match in that particular record. I may have to write a function for that. Though now that makes more sense than using grep.

Comment: @user657592 there are many ways  to get regex match counts of a record with awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gnu Awk you could use `\<` and `\>` to match beginning and end of a word, so

```
gawk '/\<GOOD\>/{++i} END{print i}'
```

will do the same as

```
grep -wc 'GOOD' file
```

If you want to count the total number of occurances (not only the number of lines, but also occurances within a given line/record) of the word `GOOD` you could use `FPAT` in Gnu Awk version 4, as

```
gawk 'BEGIN { FPAT="\\<GOOD\\>"; RS="^$" } { print NF }' file
```

If you want to count the number of exact matches of the phrase `GOOD DI` in a given record, for instance record number 3, you could use

```
gawk 'NR==3 { print patsplit($0,a,/GOOD DI/) }' file
```

Comment: will it work for the sample I've provided as a comment to the other answer?

Comment: @user657592 Are you looking for a word containing spaces like `GOOD DI`?

Comment: Yes. I want the number of occurrences of 'GOOD DI' in the record. But I want it just that way, with the space.

Comment: @user657592 So it is not a word you are looking for, but an exact match in the record. Like both `GOOD DI A` and `GOOD DIN` will both be matches?

Comment: +1 for your stamina (and for a good solution) :-) and @user657592 -- next time post some example input data and the expected outcome! That will remove the guesswork and you will get an answer a lot faster!

Comment: The count that I get should only be for the match of `GOOD DI` in the current record. If I want that for every record read, do I use NR==FNR { print patsplit($0,a,/GOOD DI/) }' file?

Comment: @user657592 If you want to match `GOOD DI` but not `GOOD DIN` add word boundaries to the regex like `/\<GOOD DI\>/`. If you want to the test for every record in the file, you could just omit the rule in front if you like.. That is: `{print patsplit($0,a,/\<GOOD DI\>/) }`

Comment: @user657592 Great! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, and it would help if you showed some of your input file, your entire script that you have so far and also the output you want to achieve.

In the mean time, as there is nothing in your question to suggest anything to the contrary, you could do the following:

```
awk 'somescript' somefile | grep --count -w 'GOOD DI'
```

Comment: Sample `GOOD DI is not as happy as GOOD DIN but GOOD DIN is not all that happy. GOOD DI is delusional`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply grep on a text string, which is what you are doing. If you really need to use grep/system something like following would be needed:

system("echo '"$0"' | grep --count -w 'foo'")

But this is no good either as count only counts lines on which it occurs not the number of times on a line which is what you are after. Or so it seems.

If you use the regex as a split seperator you get the number of split occurences +1.

So following will work:

```
awk '{printf FNR; a=split($0,myarray,/.OOD/); print "  "a-1}' file.txt
```

This would print each linenumber with the number of times your regex occured. (in this case ".OOD". Representing GOOD, FOOD, MOOD etc)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it the old fashion way

```
awk 'BEGIN{count=0} {
  for( i=1;i<=NF; i++)  {
    if( $i == "GOOD" ){
       ++count
    }
  }
}END {
  print count
}' file
```